# How to write inner dictionaries into .xlsx file in Python

Tags: python, excel

Assuming that I have the following dictionary:

```
{
    "sheet_A": {
        "2017": {
            "col1": "a", 
            "col2": "b", 
            "col3": "c", 
            "col4": "d"
        }, 
        "2018": {
            "col1": "aa", 
            "col2": "bb", 
            "col3": "cc", 
            "col4": "dd"
        }, 
        "2019": {
            "col1": "aaa", 
            "col2": "bbb", 
            "col3": "ccc", 
            "col4": "ddd"
        }
    }, 
    "sheet_B": {
        "2017": {
            "col1": "e", 
            "col2": "f", 
            "col3": "g", 
            "col4": "h"
        }, 
        "2018": {
            "col1": "ee", 
            "col2": "ff", 
            "col3": "gg", 
            "col4": "hh"
        }, 
        "2019": {
            "col1": "eee", 
            "col2": "fff", 
            "col3": "ggg", 
            "col4": "hhh"
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to create an Excel file (`.xlsx`) in the form below (note the two distinct sheets) :

[image]

I have tried to use `xlwt` but it is not suitable for my use case as I have more than 256 columns to populate per sheet.

Comment: What code do you currently have? What output (including error and warning messages) does it give you?

Comment: @AgiHammerthief Updated my question to provide some more background.

Answer (score 1):

The [`pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/) package in combination with the [`xlsxwriter`](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/) package should be able to handle this, even in case of quite large data amounts.

```
# It is assumed that the data dictionary has been assigned the name `data_dict`     

import pandas as pd

# Convert dictionaries to Pandas dataframes        
df_A = pd.DataFrame(data_dict["sheet_A"]).transpose()
df_B = pd.DataFrame(data_dict["sheet_B"]).transpose()

# Create a Pandas Excel writer using XlsxWriter as the engine
with pd.ExcelWriter('workbook.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter') as writer:
    # Write each dataframe to a different worksheet
    df_A.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet_A')
    df_B.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet_B')
```